# setup.py don't installing the requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I'm did a python library, it's my first python library
published on [pypl](https://pypi.org/project/appfly/) and [github](https://github.com/expresso/appfly)

The library works very well, but the setup() doesn't.

When I install it by `pip install`, it dowloand the appfly package but do not install the requirements: `Flask,flask_cors, Flask-SocketIO and jsonmerge`. So I need install it by myself.
If I install the dependencies myself, it's works very well, but i think it's the wrong way to use a python library right?

here is my `setup.py` file, I'm doing something wrong?

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from appfly import __version__ as version

with open('README.md') as readme_file:
    readme = readme_file.read()

# with open('HISTORY.md') as history_file:
#     history = history_file.read()

requirements = [
    'Flask==1.0.2',
    'flask_cors==3.0.6', 
    'Flask-SocketIO==3.0.2',
    'jsonmerge==1.5.2'
]

setup(
    author="Italo José G. de Oliveira",
    author_email='italo.i@live.com',
    classifiers=[
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
    ],
    description="This pkg encapsulate the base flask server configurations",
    install_requires=requirements,
    license="MIT license",
    long_description=readme,
    include_package_data=True,
    keywords='appfly',
    name='appfly',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://github.com/italojs/appfly',
    version=version,
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Comment: part of the reason is that you import from your package in the setup.py. This means that python will try loading your library before it installs it or its deps. See https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/#single-sourcing-the-version for how to single source the version correctly.

Comment: it make sense, i will try remove it

Comment: it worked, tks!

Comment: Great! would you like to write up what you did to solve it in an answer and mark it as solved? (or alternately I could turn my comment into an answer if you want)

Comment: send your first comment as answer and i mark it as a solution, it will set positive points to your account

Comment: I've reverted an edit to your question. Please see "[*Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/284827)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error is that the `setup.py` imports from the package. This means that python will try importing the library while processing the `setup.py` (ie. before any of the dependencies get installed).

Since you are only importing the package to get the version information, this import can be replaced with a different method.

An easy way to do this is to include the version information directly in the `setup.py`, but the drawback with this is that the version is no longer single sourced.

Other methods involve a bit of work but allow the version information to continue to be single sourced. See https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/ for recommendations. That page has a list of options, some of which may be better suited to your package setup than others. I personally prefer option 3:

> Set the value to a `__version__` global variable in a dedicated module
>   in your project (e.g. version.py), then have setup.py read and exec
>   the value into a variable.
>
> ...
>
> Using exec:
>
> ```
> version = {}
> with open("...sample/version.py") as fp:
>     exec(fp.read(), version)
> # later on we use: version['__version__']
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can also define the version in the `__init__.py` of your package like:

```
__version__ = "1.1.0"
```

Then, instead of importing `__version__` in your `setup.py`, you can read the **init**.py and exctract the version.

Actually, this is the solution proposed in the official Python guides:

https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using versioneer package (pandas uses it).

versioneer uses Git tags to create the version value.

## Steps

### Step 0: Use git tags

Versioneer uses yout Git tags.

### Step 1: Install versioneer

```
pip install versionner
```

### Step 2: Execute versioneer

```
versioneer install
```

### Step 3: Follow the versioneer instructions

Versioneer will ask you to do some changes in your setup.py and setup.cfg.\

In the setup.py you'll have to add something like:

```
import versioneer

setup(
    version=versioneer.get_version(),
    cmdclass=versioneer.get_cmdclass()
)
```

And in setup.cfg:

```
[versioneer]
VCS = git
style = pep440
versionfile_source = your_project_name/_version.py
versionfile_build = your_project_name/_version.py
tag_prefix = v
parentdir_prefix =
```

**Note**: In the example I set "tag_prefix = v" because I like tagging like: v0.1.0, v1.0.0 and so on

After that, try:

```
python setup.py version
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate how this would work using `versioneer`?

Comment: please be more specific with what can be done :D