# Install dependencies first when installing my package via setup.py with pip

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have a proyect with the following structure:

```
code/
    setup.py
    dependencies.txt
    my_package/
        version.py
        __init__.py 
        my_module.py
        ...
```

my_package/version.py:

```
__version__ = "X.Y.Z"
```

my_package/__init__.py:

```
from .version import __version__
from .my_module import MyClass
```

In setup.py I am retrieving the version of my_package on the fly:

```
from setuptools import setup
from my_package import __version__

setup(
version=__version__,
...
install_requires=[..dependencies list..])
```

I can generate the installation package with `python setup.py sdist`. It will generate the file `my_package-X.Y.Z.tar.gz`.

The problem is that when I install it in a clean virtual environment with `pip install my_package-X.Y.Z.tar.gz`, I get an error in `setup.py` because when importing the package version, the `__init__.py` file will be executed before the dependencies are installed and the line `from .my_module import MyClass` will fail because `my_module` makes use of the dependencies.

¿Is there a way to make `pip` or `setup.py` to install the dependencies before any other step (not manually), or I have to hard code the version number every time it changes?

I know it may not be not a big deal, but it is something I've been trying to solve with no success.

Comment: "*Is there a way to make pip or setup.py to install the dependencies before any other step…?*" No. Go a different route — parse `version.py` instead of importing it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54630384/7976758 . See how I do it in the real code: [SQLObject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/836763622ef5b93f933cbd712ef7b65cdb742183/setup.py#L7-L17), [mimedecode](https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode/blob/eaca10a6f9782430108b05194ff7b0d961d124d5/setup.py#L7-L17).

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem perfectly.